# Query list in designer workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, query

I have created a approval workflow using SharePoint Designer workflow. I want to query the task list to get the task with minimum due date for the current task approver.

Below is the scenario :

I have created a list named list2 with two columns Approver(person or group) and minimal due date(date time). Approver column is designed to store unique values. The minimal due date column should always store the minimum due date from the task list for the approver.

What I have done till now is assign due date in "Minimal due date" column when a task is created after the the two dates.

**Where I am stuck is** how to handle "Minimal due date" column when the task approved, rejected cancelled or deleted.

My idea was to get minimum due date from the task list where assigned to the specific user and status is not started, but I am not able to find any action to support this.

Could someone please suggest if this approach is feasible or suggest some other approach to achieve the task.

Comment: Try carrying over the list ID from the first list to the second.  Make a new field in the second list called ItemID or whatever.  Pass the ID of the first lists items to the second.  Then you can use the ItemID column in the second list to connect the two seperate list items together in workflow.  in you workflow setting say get this value from this list where ID = ItemID.

Comment: Second list contain one item corresponding to several items in first list. The second list has a Person field as Unique and first list have multiple entries for same person

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using SPD2013 for this, if possible. You can make REST calls to the list using the `Call Web Service` activity and it makes filtering a list of items, then iterating through the results, a lot more straightforward.

See also: [Call HTTP Web Service Using SharePoint Designer 2013 (SPD)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/58e23e/call-http-web-service-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-spd/)